# openiddict disable endpoint routing

Tags: openiddict

I have an Asp.Net Core project setup using openiddict.  One of the packages I use (Asp.Net Odata) does not support endpoint routing, so I've disabled it in ConfigureServices

`services.AddControllers(c=>c.EnableEndpointRouting = false)`

The problem is when I do this the openiddict extension method `GetOpenIddictServerRequest` returns null.  Everything works fine as long as endpoint routing is enabled

```
 [HttpPost("~/oauth/token"), Produces("application/json")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Token()
        {
            var request = HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest();
...
```

I register openiddict as shown below

```
services.AddOpenIddict()
                .AddCore(options =>
                {
                    // Configure OpenIddict to use the Entity Framework Core stores and entities.
                    options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                                   .UseDbContext<MiPayOnlineCoreContext>();
                })

                .AddServer(options =>
                {

                    options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
                    options.SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(11));

                    options.SetTokenEndpointUris("/oauth/token");

                    options.AllowPasswordFlow();
                    options.AllowRefreshTokenFlow();                    

                    options.SetIssuer(new Uri(authSettings[nameof(JWTSettings.Issuer)]));
                    options.AddSigningCertificate(certificate);
                    options.AddEncryptionCertificate(certificate);

                    // Mark the "email", "profile" and "roles" scopes as supported scopes.
                    options.RegisterScopes(OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Email,
                                           OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Profile,
                                           OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles);


                    options.UseAspNetCore()
                           .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration()
                           .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
                           .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
                           .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                           .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough();

                });
```

Is it possible to make this work with endpoint routing disabled?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue you describe locally. Make sure `app.UseAuthentication()` appears quite early in the `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` method. If it still doesn't work, consider posting a repro on GitHub so I can take a look.

Comment: I've pushed a sample [https://github.com/mmeyer-civic/openiddictdisableenpointrouting](https://github.com/mmeyer-civic/openiddictdisableenpointrouting).  The login parameters/url are found in the InitializeAsync method of Startup.cs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in your code: you didn't put `app.UseMvc()` at the right place.

Make sure it appears after `app.UseAuthentication()` and `app.UseAuthorization()` and the error will go away.

Comment: Firstly, this is an awesome piece of work, your knowledge of the asp auth stack is incredible. I will be sponsoring this project once I have my rig up and running. Second, support like this is indispensable and folk like yourself are in short supply, thanks for taking the time to respond here and thanks for all the hard work!

Comment: @MoonKnight haha, thanks for your kind words! 